# Macbook Restarts Automatically After RAM Changed?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, kernel-panic

I have a MacBook Pro with OX 10.9.3 installed having 5 Gb of RAM. Yesterday I changed the RAM, and since that, my MacBook restarts automatically while working. I thought it was an issue with the new RAM, so I removed the extra RAM, but still getting same problem.

Here is the log of my Unexpected restart of the machine :

```
Anonymous UUID:       4881DA70-6C9B-1A89-9EC1-36528CFD0B80

Sat Oct 11 12:51:54 2014
Panic (cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801a2dc43e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff801a234236, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff806f98d0b8, CR3: 0x000000001d36c000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x0000000000000002, RBX: 0xffffff806f18d000, RCX: 0xffffff801a234248, RDX: 0xffffff801a8cab40
RSP: 0xffffff80747bbe30, RBP: 0xffffff80747bbe60, RSI: 0xffffff801a8cafb0, RDI: 0x000000000000005f
R8:  0x000000000000005f, R9:  0x00000000000000ff, R10: 0xffffffffffffffff, R11: 0x000000000424809e
R12: 0x0000000000000005, R13: 0x0000000000000005, R14: 0xffffff80217256d0, R15: 0xffffff801a8ca4e8
RFL: 0x0000000000010093, RIP: 0xffffff801a234236, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff806f98d0b8, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80747bbac0 : 0xffffff801a222f79 
0xffffff80747bbb40 : 0xffffff801a2dc43e 
0xffffff80747bbd10 : 0xffffff801a2f3976 
0xffffff80747bbd30 : 0xffffff801a234236 
0xffffff80747bbe60 : 0xffffff801a233ae7 
0xffffff80747bbe80 : 0xffffff801a24ef78 
0xffffff80747bbee0 : 0xffffff801a236b7f 
0xffffff80747bbf70 : 0xffffff801a235d5c 
0xffffff80747bbfb0 : 0xffffff801a2d7607 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13F34

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9477416E-7BCA-3679-AF97-E1EAAD3DD5A0
Kernel slide:     0x000000001a000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801a200000
System model name: MacBook5,1 (Mac-F42D89A9)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 42674924725
Last loaded kext at 5487254343: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9aab3000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.7
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    683.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.21
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   217.92.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   640.36
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.7
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 686.4.1
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBook5,1, BootROM MB51.007D.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.40f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353432382D3034302E4130314C4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f3 14616, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS543216L9SA02, 160.04 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS21N
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you should test your RAM

- Using the Apple tool for that

To launch the hardware tests, boot your Mac with Option-D held down immediately after you hear the boot chimes, and the tests will download from Apple's servers.

- Using 3d party tools for that:

[MemTest for Mac OS X Tests your RAM](http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/03/memtest-mac-ram-test/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all RAM and reseat it. Do not reinstall the upgrade until you can determine the cause of the problem. Unfortunately, you may have physically damaged something during the memory upgrade.

Also, just for kicks, did you try zapping the PRAM? I've never seen this have an effect on any of my machines but it's worth a try.

Comment: I haven't seen zapping the PRAM have any effect since System 7, but resetting the SMC might have some traction

Comment: I just gave myself a nightmare about 32 restarts using Conflict Catcher... I need to lie down a while... ;-)

Comment: Me neither regarding the PRAM, but even the Genius Bar still recommends it when troubleshooting to this day.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had something like that happen to me at one point. Try taking all the ram out, blow out the memory slots carefully and put in one memory stick at a time and see if you get any issues.